# ElasticSearch 2.X Scroll API Specify Number of Hits Per Request

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to specify the number of hits to return in a scroll?  Right now whenever I call `GET _search/scroll?scroll=10m&scroll_id=XXX`  I only get back 10 hits at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the `page-size` while creating the initial scroll context.

**Example:**

```
GET <index_name>/_search?scroll=1m&size=1
```

Subsequent scroll calls will return one page of results

**Example:**

```
GET  _search/scroll?scroll=1m&scroll_id=xxx
```